# Polymorphism relationships

Tags: java, polymorphism

I'm new in inheritance and polymorphism so I always got confused. I was tasked to write a simple quiz program that will have 3 types of question, which is ShortAnswerQuestion, FillInBlankQuestion and TrueFalseQuestion.

My only problem is how I could get the answer form these three classes. I able to display the question but I can't figure out how to get the answer.

Here are my codes.

Question.class

```
public class Question{

private String question;


public Question(String question) {
    this.question = question;

}


public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}


public String getAnswer() {
    return "";      // here I think is the problem. What should I put here to display the answer?
}


public boolean checkAnswer(String ans)
{
    return true; // Same as this one.
}

}
```

ShortAnswerQuestion.class

```
public class ShortAnswerQuestion extends Question {

private String answer;

public ShortAnswerQuestion(String question, String answer) {
    super(question);
    this.answer = answer;
   }

}
```

FillInBlankQuestion.class

```
public class FillInBlankQuestion extends Question{

private String answer;

public FillInBlankQuestion(String question, String answer) {
    super(question);
    this.answer = answer;
   }

}
```

TrueFalseQuestion.class

```
public class TrueFalseQuestion extends Question{


private String answer;

public TrueFalseQuestion(String question, String answer) {
    super(question);
    this.answer = answer;
}

}
```

SimpleQuiz.class

```
public class SimpleQuiz {

private ArrayList<Question> myQuestions;
private int currentQuestion;

public SimpleQuiz()
{
    myQuestions = new ArrayList<>();
    //some sample questions...
    myQuestions.add(new ShortAnswerQuestion("What is the color of apple?","RED"));
    myQuestions.add(new ShortAnswerQuestion("Who invents telephone?","Alexander Bell"));
    myQuestions.add(new FillInBlankQuestion("ML is a __________?\nFill in the Blanks","GAME"));
    myQuestions.add(new FillInBlankQuestion("COC is a __________?\nFill in the Blanks","GAME"));
    myQuestions.add(new TrueFalseQuestion("Oreo and Cream-O are the same.\nTrue or False","FALSE"));
    myQuestions.add(new TrueFalseQuestion("Is Mars habitable?\nTrue or False","TRUE"));


    myQuestions = shuffleList (myQuestions);
    currentQuestion = 0;
}


    public String getCurrentQuestion()
    {
        return myQuestions.get(currentQuestion).getQuestion();
    }


    public String getCurrentAnswer()
    {
        return myQuestions.get(currentQuestion).getAnswer();
    }


    public boolean checkCurrentAnswer(String answer)
    {
       return myQuestions.get(currentQuestion).checkAnswer(answer);
    }


    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return currentQuestion < myQuestions.size() - 1;
    }

    public void next() throws Exception 
    {
        if(currentQuestion == myQuestions.size()-1)
        {
            throw new Exception("There are no more questions.");
        }
        currentQuestion++;
    }


private ArrayList<Question> shuffleList (ArrayList<Question> inputList)
    {
            ArrayList<Question> randomList = new ArrayList<Question>();

            Random r=new Random();
            int randomIndex=0;
            while(inputList.size() > 0)
            {
               randomIndex=r.nextInt(inputList.size());  
               randomList.add(inputList.get(randomIndex));   
               inputList.remove(randomIndex);   
            }

            return randomList;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of your requirement.
(polymorphism and how to use it)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class A04 {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
     List<Question> l = new ArrayList<>();
     l.add(new A04().new ShortAnswerQuestion("Who was the first man on earth?", "Adam"));
     l.add(new A04().new TrueFalseQuestion("Is java hard to learn ?", Boolean.FALSE));
     l.add(new A04().new Question("Question with no answer ?"));
     for(Question q: l)
     {   
         System.out.println(q.question);
         System.out.println(q.getAnswer());
     }        


}

class Question
{
    String question;
    Question(String question)
    {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public String getAnswer()
    {
        if(this instanceof ShortAnswerQuestion)
        { 
            //downcast since the value for answer is within SAQ
            return ((ShortAnswerQuestion) this).answer;
        };
        if(this instanceof TrueFalseQuestion)
        {
            boolean b = ((TrueFalseQuestion) this).answer;
            if(b) return "True!";
            return "False!";
        };

        return "There is no answer defined yet for the above question";
    }

}

class ShortAnswerQuestion extends Question
{

    String answer;
    ShortAnswerQuestion(String question, String answer)
    {
        super(question);
        this.answer = answer;
    }   
}

class TrueFalseQuestion extends Question
{

    Boolean answer;
    TrueFalseQuestion(String question, Boolean answer)
    {
        super(question);
        this.answer = answer;
    }   
}
}
```

output

```
Who was the first man on earth?
Adam

Is java hard to learn ?
False!

Question with no answer ?
There is no answer defined yet for the above question
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to "get" the answer, "answer" has to be an attribute of the object and you need a method that return this attribute. Problem is that you gave an "answer" attribute to each subclasses of question.
As any type of question has an answer you should give this attribute and the method to get it to the superclass Question (this is how you should think polymorphism) .

You then could consider adding a method tryAnswer in Question that take a string as parameter and checks if it matches with the answer of the question.